# Our Lexus 08 I bought a new battery cause it died out on us but everything lights up just car won’t start or click over it is button start type

Tags: lexus, no-crank-no-start

Lexus 2008 car; I just bought a new battery thinking it needed it, died out while driving it. It is button start. Everything else works fine: horn, windows, unlocks. It doesn’t even click over, no sound.

Comment: Is the new battery fully charged?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any weird dash light indicators showing, like something green resembling a key? Might be blinking?

Answer (score 0):

Some car manufacturers apply safety mesures when car computers run out of power. [Here](https://www.cashcarsbuyer.com/reset-car-computer-after-replacing-battery/) explains how to reset ECU and other electronic units when the battery is replaced.